# SSRS to Excel - How to Fit all the Columns in one Page

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have developed a Report using SSRS Report Builder 3.0. When I export to PDF, all columns fit on a single page. But when I export it to Excel and see the print preview/page layout, some of the columns went to the next page.

I know that I can click the "Fit all columns on one page" option, but my end users print this report multiple times per day and they would rather not have that extra step. Is it possible to have this option checked when exporting to Excel?

Comment: I believe if you append the data to an existing template file with this setting checked it will work.  W/o using a 3rd party add in, I know of no way to do this on export to a new file.

Comment: Yep, you are right. there is no way to do this through SSRS.  I created an Excel Macro for the end user. This was the quick and easy solution.

Comment: Hey @AlaaAwad can you give me a hint to your macro? I need totally the same thing but cannot figure it out... I just need the excel part with the macro, no SSRS stuff :) Thanks in advance